# WPF User Control Library - Does not exsist in the namespace

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, wpf-controls

I'm new to WPF.
I'm trying to create a WPF application with WPF User Control Library. 
But when I try to build or run the project I'm getting the following errors. 
I have added the reference to the starting project.

**The name "HoverButton" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:HomeSchool_KinectControls;assembly=HomeSchool_KinectControls;"**

When I remove the Canves and other elements inside it and build, It successfully built. But when I try to use the HoverButton the error is appearing again and the project is not getting build.

[image]

I have seen it's kinda bug in the VS and I tried following:

1. Restarting VS
2. Change the Targeting Build Platform

And it doesn't work.

Please help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it is seen that you're trying to access the Hoverbutton from a certain library.

It is not possible to access a library without adding a reference to it.Right Click on **References** under the solution explorer and select **Add reference**. Now browse to the required library or select it if it is in **GAC**. It will solve your issue.

Comment: HoverButton is inside the HomeSchool_KinectControls project. I'm trying to access it from HomeSchool_Client project. So I have already added the reference of HomeSchool_KinectControls to the HomeSchool_Client project.

Comment: The error seems to be due to not adding reference, since the error clearly says that. So ensure that the reference added is correct.